# How do I get enode in Parity

Tags: parity

I'm setting a private blockchain using parity rust client.

In `geth`I can use `admin.nodeInfo` and get enode from there. But how can I get enode in parity client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parity`'s enode info is written to the console when you start the program.

```
user@Kumquat:~$ parity 
2016-08-26 00:57:35 Starting Parity/v1.2.2-beta/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.10.0
2016-08-26 00:57:35 Using a conversion rate of Ξ1 = US$11.22 (21220608000 wei/gas)
2016-08-26 00:57:35 Configured for Frontier/Homestead using Ethash engine
2016-08-26 00:57:36 Public node URL: enode://031b1e872cea345c5b6b2ff9dfc16213021071bb320987fdf9881f4500880e57a5a8d6b8b57aaf0de263df0a88d757f978039e09fa9758c4d814850c4172ddf7@0.0.0.0:30303
...
```

Your enode info is `enode://031b1e872cea345c5b6b2ff9dfc16213021071bb320987fdf9881f4500880e57a5a8d6b8b57aaf0de263df0a88d757f978039e09fa9758c4d814850c4172ddf7@0.0.0.0:30303`.

`0.0.0.0` is your localhost. Replace it with your computer's IP address if you want to connect to the `parity` node from other computers.

Comment: Thank you, I've found that. I'd like to automate the process for private Blockchain , e.g. to make a query to parity, save enode to index.html, serve it from local web server , and other nodes will curl this URL to construct their bootstrap setting

Comment: the only way is to parse the log? .. or to modify `parity` source code with a new JSON RPC method to get nodeid?

Comment: I just scanned through the source code and could not find any `admin` API - see https://github.com/ethcore/parity/blob/master/parity/rpc_apis.rs#L51-L60 . So your logs may be the only way.

Comment: I searched and tested the JSONRPC API documented at https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-ethcore-module but no nodeInfo available.

Comment: @IgorBarinov - there **is** a JSON RPC method `parity_enode` to get enode info. See my answer dated Feb 10, 2017 below.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to get enode information is to send a `POST` request with the header `Content-Type: application/json` to the RPC port of the node with the following body:

`{ "method": "parity_enode", "params": [], "id": 1, "jsonrpc": "2.0" }`

Official documentation: https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module.html#parity_enode

Comment: here is a handy snippet: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k --data '{ "method": "parity_enode", "params": [], "id": 1, "jsonrpc": "2.0" }' -X POST http://localhost:8545

Answer (score 4):

Parity doesn't include a Javascript interpreter. However, as per the documentation, if you [first install node/NPM](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Basic-Usage#nodejs-cli-console) then you'll be able to install and use the existing Ethereum Web3 API.

```
$ npm install web3

$ node
> Web3 = require("web3")
> web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
> web3.eth.blockNumber
743397
```

Comment: There is no admin.nodeInfo if not to use --geth compatibility which is like to avoid due to bugs in geth

Answer (score 2):

Finally I wrote a workaround with a bash script. I run it on a node using `foreman` and it writes `nodeId` to a static web server. Other nodes use `curl` to get nodeId for bootstrapping.

```
touch /var/log/parity.log
tail -f /var/log/parity.log | while read LOGLINE
do
   [[ "${LOGLINE}" == *"enode"* ]] && echo $LOGLINE | grep -oEi '(enode.*@)' > /var/www/index.html
done
```